# Data cardinality error during Inference for an Encoder-Decoder model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, inference, summarization, encoder-decoder

I'm making a text summarization model using the gigaword dataset and Tensorflow. i followed examples from various places like github and kaggle to make my Encoder-Decoder model. After i was done training the model and setting up the inference model, i wanted to test it but it popped up a ValueError during the process. Below is my architecture for the encoder and decoder model and its inference model:

```
embedding_dim = 128
hidden_units = 256

#Encoder Model
encoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_data,))
encoder_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(data_total_word,embedding_dim,trainable=True)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_LSTM = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_units, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder_LSTM(encoder_embeddings)
encoder_state = [encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c]

#Decoder Model
decoder_inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None,))
decoder_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(label_total_word,embedding_dim,trainable=True)(decoder_inputs)
decoder_LSTM = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(hidden_units, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
decoder_outputs, decoder_forward, decoder_backward = decoder_LSTM(decoder_embeddings, initial_state=[state_h, state_c])
decoder_dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(label_total_word, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
```

Below is my inference model:

```
#INFERENCE
encoder_model = tf.keras.models.Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_state)
decoder_state_input_h = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(hidden_units,))
decoder_state_input_c = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(hidden_units,))
decoder_hidden_states_input =  tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_data,hidden_units))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_hidden_states_input,decoder_state_input_h,decoder_state_input_c]

decoder_outputs2, state_h2, state_c2 = decoder_LSTM(decoder_embeddings, initial_state=[decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c])
decoder_states = [state_h2, state_c2]
decoder_outputs2 = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs2)
decoder_model = tf.keras.models.Model([decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs, [decoder_outputs2] + decoder_states)
```

I put together a function to predict and decode text using the inference model:

```
def generate_summary(input_news):
  input_seq = data_tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(input_news)
  input_seq = pad_sequences(input_seq,maxlen=max_data,padding='post')
  states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)
  
  target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1))
  target_seq[0, 0] = label_tokenizer.word_index['hajime']
  print(target_seq)
  eos = label_tokenizer.word_index['owari']
  
  summary = ''
  while True:
    output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict([target_seq]+ states_value)
    idx = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])

    if idx == eos:
      break
    
    word = ''
    if idx > 0:
      word = label_tokenizer.index_word[idx]
      summary += ' '+ word
    
    target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1))
    target_seq[0, 0] = idx
    states_value = [h, c]

  return summary
```

it is in the **generate_summary()** function where the data cardinality error popped up with the following message:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1, 139, 139, 139
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

the error pointed at the **decoder_model.predict()**. If you would like to see the entire code you can use this google colab link to get the full picture: [Google Colab Link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1u-or_1YU3WDhurSLdouBgLqz82rU_Wl2?usp=sharing)

I tried reshaping the **target_seq **for the inference but to no avail. I don't know if its an issue with the model architecture or just the shape of the input data for the inference.